# php get latitude from address without api key

Tags: php, google-maps

I have function that get address and return latitude and longitude.

The problem is that after a while i'm getting 0.00000 for both lat & lng. I guess that i need to add "&key=API_KEY" to the url, and if i got it right it's cost money.

Is there any other way to get address lat & lng ?

```
function get_address_lat_lng ($address)
{

    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

    $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($prepAddr).'&sensor=false');

    $output= json_decode($geocode);

    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    return (array('lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng) );
}
```

Comment: for reistered  user  (for obtain google key) google maps  new policies .. give  a free amount  each month for some operation 
 check google maps site for this  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - hi. so why do i get 0.0000 for lat & lng? I don't have lot of traffic...

Comment: you have not apikey  .. so you have not result  .. you must have a valid apikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ipLookUp () {
  $.ajax('http://ip-api.com/json')
   .then(
    function success(response) {
      console.log('User\'s Location Data is ', response);
      console.log('User\'s Country ', response.country);
    },

    function fail(data, status) {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ', status);
    }
  );
}
ipLookUp()
```

Check your console logs on browsers but this is based on IP of client.

Comment: @AhmedShahin : while you are rethinking your answer, consider that your php looks a lot like js.

Comment: you can write javascript and call it in php ... do you want me to make live example ?

Comment: @AhmedShahin - Hi there. Your script return latitude and longitude by user location. I need it by address...

Comment: @MrUpsidown  the one am using do not use api key  that what he needed ..